# UITableViewCell numberOfLines not work at first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a UILabel in a UITableViewCell, I want it to be multilines according to context, and I use masonry to manage autolayout, here is the code
CommunityTableViewCell.m :

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {    
        _postContentLabel = [UILabel new];
        _postContentLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        _postContentLabel.font = DefaultFont(15);
        _postContentLabel.textColor = COLOR(117, 117, 117);
        [self.contentView addSubview:_postContentLabel];

        [self makeConstraints];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)makeConstraints{

    [_postContentLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(_userAvatar);
        make.right.equalTo(_groupNameButton);
        make.top.equalTo(_postTitleLabel.mas_bottom).offset(20);
        make.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(@20);
    }];
}

- (void)updateCellWithModel:(PostsModel *)model{

    if (model.content && ![model.content isEqualToString:@""]) {
        _postContentLabel.text = model.content;
        _postContentLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = _postContentLabel.frame.size.width;
        [_postContentLabel sizeToFit];
    } else{
        _postContentLabel = nil;
        [_postContentLabel removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [self updateConstraints];
}

- (void)updateConstraints {
    //some other code here

    [super updateConstraints];
}
```

CommunityViewController.m :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _communityTableView = [UITableView new];
    _communityTableView.delegate = self;
    _communityTableView.dataSource = self;
    _communityTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80;
    _communityTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    [_communityTableView registerClass:[CommunityTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CommunityTableViewCell"];
    [self.view addSubview:_communityTableView];

    [self makeConstraints];
    [self requestPostData];
}

- (void)makeConstraints{
    [_communityTableView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        make.edges.equalTo(self.view).insets(padding);
    }];
}

- (void)requestPostData{
    [[NetEngine engine] GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"posts"] success:^(id responseObject) {
        //receive the data
        [self.communityTableView reloadData];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {

    }];
}

#pragma mark - TableView DataSource & Delegate

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return _postArrary.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CommunityTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CommunityTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

     PostsModel *model = _postArrary[indexPath.row];
     //some other code
     [cell updateCellWithModel:model];
     return cell;
}
```

enter code here

It doesn't show up to 2 lines as I wish, it shows only one line, but when I scroll down and back or pull to refresh the tableview, it shows 2 lines.

I don't know what's going on.

Comment: The line `[_postContentLabel sizeToFit];` right after initializing the label is somewhat strange to me. Can you remove that line and test?

Comment: @FahriAzimov Well, thanks for answer my question, but I tried it, and it's not work.

Comment: That was not an answer, just a suggestion. Can you please post more details on the issue? Is this a custom cell? Do you reuse it? Also, if it's a custom cell, do you implement `layoutSubviews` and `prepareForReuse` methods?

Comment: @DavidHu, set default frame size for `_postContentLabel`, also you might want to read more about `-sizeToFit` how it behaves and things, also consider the hierarchy of your codes calling `sizeToFit` right after declaration `[UILabel new]` with no rect size and reference for `sizeToFit` is not a good idea..

Comment: @0yeoj Ok, I've update my question

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: @ZassX and I use masonry to manage all the constraints

Comment: I had similar problem. Was using SnapKit (same stuff as masonry), deleted pod, solved it using auto layout. 

Set label lines to 0, apply constraints so there are no warnings.
In code set:

self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0; // set to whatever your "average" cell height is

Comment: @ZassX It works! I set self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 180; And It work as I want! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Well this means all rows will have height 180, so this is not cool. Make sure constraints are applied to elements so it resizes by itself.

Comment: @ZassX Yes I know it's not cool, but I think I have made it resize by itself already according to `_communityTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;` Would you give so more details?

Comment: @DavidHu As I said, if you put constraints to all UI elements in cell then it is auto resizing. You can test and put no text in some cells and a lot of text in others. If it auto resizes then you made it correct. :)

Comment: @ZassX Thanks a lot! I'll test my app carefully